# How to make a table/Grid in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to create something like the image below in my iOS app. What is the best way to approach this, note the rows and the columns can vary.[image]

The easiest way I thought of was to insert html table into UIWebView, but not sure if there is a way to intercept radio button clicks like there is for a regular button by making it a "href link"

Comment: Try some searching: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+grid

Comment: I already looked these, I don't want to write for loops to accomplish something that could be done easier (I think). Why wouldn't html table work here?

Comment: Your question provides no context. There is no way to know what is the best solution without knowing more. Using a web view may be OK but probably not.

Comment: What does context have to do with this, It's clear a grid with rows and columns where you can select an option!

Comment: I know it's a grid. My point is that there are several possible solutions. But without any context about where this will be used and how, people are just offering opinions on possible solutions. You'll get better answers if you provide more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little unrelated to what you have as the title of your question, but maybe look at using [`UISegmentedControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html).  It's the closest thing to radial buttons that exists in the Objective-C world.

If you went with a segmented control, you no longer need to worry about columns, intercepting touches, and a lot of the other problems you mention in your Question - it could all be done in a normal `UITableView`.  You would have to create some custom `UITableViewCell` subclasses to get the segmented controls in, but there are a lot of good tutorials ([YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=custom+table+view+cell+ios+7&sm=3), [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014105/where-is-a-good-tutorial-for-making-a-custom-uitableviewcell)) on how to set those up.

Comment: Hmm, not a bad idea, it can work, even though not as nice looking.

Comment: @IronMan1980: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder I guess.  The look of the segmented controls have grown on me since I started using them a few months ago.  Radial buttons look a little aged to me now - then again maybe that's what you're going for.  As I said, to each his own.

Comment: You do have a good point. I decided this is what I will go for, it works for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

From iOS 6+ you could use the [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UICollectionView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UICollectionView) class to build up a grid. Managing the values in the data source (representing if a radio is checked or not) is something you'd have to implement yourself.

Comment: I was going to suggest this as well, but I think the segmented control will be easier, because it provides so many build-in features for tracking what is selected, where he would have to implement all of those on his own (as you mentioned in your edit).

Comment: I agree. I would have used UICollectionView for more complex grid may be photo album, but I just needed a simple grid showing what was selected.